# Convert MAME cheat to Lua script

Tags: lua, emulation

I am trying to convert a MAME cheat to a Lua script:

```
<mamecheat version="1">
  <cheat desc="Cheat description">
    <script state="run">
      <action>audiocpu.pw@F018=0000</action>
    </script>
  </cheat>
</mamecheat>
```

When I'm displaying the content of @F018 on the HUD, it displays successfully the id of the current music :

```
audiocpu = manager:machine().devices[":audiocpu"];
mem = audiocpu.spaces["program"];
print(mem:read_i8(0xF018));
```

But when i write 0 to the memory, the hud content displays 0, but the music does not stops...

```
mem:write_i8(0xF018, 0x0000);
```

Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was reading and writing 8 bits but the data was in 16 bits.
So, this is the correct syntax:

```
print(mem:read_i16(0xF018));
```

and

```
mem:write_i16(0xF018, 0x0000);
```